# HTML5 Canvas Context.drawImage not showing up

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, draw

I am trying to make a drawing program with HTML canvas. You can see a version of it here: https://naclcaleb.github.io/Draw

My architecture works somewhat like this:

I have a master Canvas object, which contains a list of layers that it draws.

Each layer has a list of "Strokes". Each stroke contains a list of actions required to draw it.

I've had a few problems with lag. First, it was taking too long to draw all the strokes in the list.

I solved this by "rendering" the layer every time a stroke is added, so it's just an image.

That worked fine, except that I still had to draw every stroke when the user pressed Ctrl+Z, so I could reset the render.

So every time they tried to undo, it would take a while to compute - usable, but not ideal.

To fix this, I tried the same approach with each stroke - when it's done being created, "render" it by drawing it on a different hidden canvas, then turning it into an image with a DataURL.

(NOTE: I did try using `getImageData` and `putImageData` instead, but then it would replace the previous strokes with empty pixels)

And now I'm getting a pretty big problem:

Whenever I make a stroke, it immediately disappears. But once I press Ctrl+Z, all the previous strokes suddenly become visible.

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now.

Here's basically what happens:

1. The mouse is released, which triggers this event listener (found in the layer class):

   ```
   this.el.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e){
           //You can ignore this line...
           if (active){
               //...and this if statement. It just handles the erasers, and has been tested to work
               if (that.erasing){
                   CURRENT_TOOL.currentStroke.actions.push({
                       func: ctx.setGlobalCompositeOperation,
                       params: ["source-over"]
                   });
               }

               //Have the current stroke create its render - I have used console.log to ensure that this does get run, and that the dataURL produced shows the correct image.
               CURRENT_TOOL.currentStroke.createRender();

               //The endStroke method returns the currentStroke, which I grab here
               var newStroke = CURRENT_TOOL.endStroke(ctx);

               //"that" is just a reference to the layer instance

               //Add it to the strokes list
               that.strokes.push(newStroke);

               //Update the render
               that.updateRender();
           }
       });
   ```
2. As you saw in the event listener, it calls an `updateRender` method. Here is that method (also in the layer class):

   ```
   //Clear the canvas
   this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.el.width, this.el.height);

   //Put the LAYER's render onto the screen
   this.ctx.putImageData(this.render, 0, 0);

   //Draw the stroke - I'll give you the draw function, but I've confirmed it does get run
   this.strokes[this.strokes.length-1].draw();


   //Now get the image data and update the render
   this.render = this.ctx.getImageData(0,0, this.el.width, this.el.height);
   ```
3. As you saw in that function, it calls the stroke's draw function (found in the stroke class):

   ```
   draw(){
   //Ignore this if
   if (this.render === undefined){
       for (var i = 0;i<this.actions.length;i++){
           this.actions[i].func.apply(this.ctx, this.actions[i].params);
       }
   }
   else {
       //I've used console.log to confirm that this runs. 

       //Draw the render
       this.ctx.drawImage(this.render, 0, 0);

       //I've also console.logged the dataurl of the layer before and after drawing the image, and neither have the render drawn on them. 


   }
   }
   ```

This seems to say that the `this.ctx.drawImage` is not being run? Or that it's being run in the wrong way?

Anyways, that's that, and though I apologize for the longevity of this question, I'm hoping someone can help me. This is really my last resort.

**One more thing: I got it to work in the link I gave earlier by rendering the layer using the same method I render the strokes - using an image with a dataURL instead of `getImageData` and `putImageData`. I'm not really sure what to think about that...**

Comment: I can't seem to get the code to format right. Could someone help with that too?

Comment: Just one thing. You will get help much faster if you add a code snippet.

Comment: What kind of code snippet?

Comment: `this.render` is the result of getImageData()? Then its an ImageData and can not be used as is with drawImage. It's quite unclear to me what it is you want to do,( still early here) but it smells good the XY problem. Anyway, drawImage accepts only html and svg image elements, canvas elements ( even its own) html video elements and ImageBitmaps. You should have errors thrown in your web-dev console complaining about things that didn't go right.

Comment: No. One of the `this.render` values belongs to the layer. That one is an ImageData. The one belonging to the stroke IS an HTMLImageElement. I get absolutely no errors in the console.

Comment: And are you sure this HTMLImageElement has finished loading before you try to draw it? Also, I still don't get it, your "layers" are canvases? If so, draw these directly on the master using master_ctx.drawImage(layer_canvas, 0,0). No need for image or imagedata.

Comment: My layers are a class with a canvas stored in `this.el`. And I'm not sure how you would test that. I've console.logged it and saw an output. And it's a dataURL image, so it doesn't have to load from a different source or anything.

Comment: To load an image in an <img> element is always an asynchronous operation, even when the src is a dataURL. You must wait until it's been loaded and parsed before being able to use it with drawImage (listen for its onload event). But once again, if your layers are canvases, then you don't need to call toDataURL on it, nor to load an <img>. You can directly draw these HTMLCanvasElements using your master's context drawImage. drawImage does accept HTMLCanvasElement as source, and doing this is synchronous, and faster than any other way.

Comment: Alright, I'll try that.

Comment: Spot-on, thanks! If you make an answer out of it I can mark it correct.

Comment: @MaxMartynov I finally realized what you meant by a snippet. I've never seen that before...